# Why can't I post an object containing both a model and additional parameters using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

Why can't I post an object containing both a model and a integer(id) from mvc view to action  using jQuery?
I am trying to post an object containing a model and a  (int)ID from my view to MVC action.The problem is, I can post id(int) but cannot pass Model, while the controller receives the ID correctly but Model is empty.
I tried many things but it doesn't work and Model is always empty.But when I just pass model on its own then it works(not empty). Can someone suggest me some idea?

**jQuery Code:**

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '@Url.Action("AddProfileAddress", "Account")',
    data: {
        model1: $('#frmAddProfileAddress').serialize(),
        id: 3
    }
});
```

**Controller**

```vb
<HttpPost()> _
Public Function AddProfileAddress(ByVal model1 As Address, id As Integer) As ActionResult
{
    ...
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you put the id on the model? Why keep it separate?

Comment: You need a [ViewModel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc) containing your Model and your Id.

Comment: i cannot pass through model and need to pass it separately.I have outlined solution below.Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution is below:

```
             $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '@Url.Action("AddProfileAddress", "Account")',
                        data: $('#frmAddProfileAddress').serialize()+"&addresstypeid="+addresstypeid,
                        beforeSend: function () {
                            //launchpreloader();
                            $("div#spinner").fadeIn("fast");
                        },
                        complete: function () {
                            //stopPreloader();
                            $("div#spinner").fadeOut("fast");
                        },
                        success: function (result) {
                            //alert(result);
                        }
                    });
```